# Selecting from two tables issue

Tags: php

This is was am trying to do table A has all profession categories & table B has users details.i want select from the 2 tables and match up categories selected,if user select 'web developer' from a dropdown of categories.i want to display list of users under web developer.

```
<?php 
$q = intval($_GET['q']); 
//select state of the two tables here
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

?> 
///
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Check your question.

Comment: selecting from 2 databases or 2 tables in the same database?

Answer (score 0):

it's unclear from the question and lack of database details what and how to do the sql query ( which I think is what you are actually asking for ) but something along these lines perhaps.

```
select * from `tableB` b
    left outer join `tableA` a on a.`professionid`=b.`professionid`
    where a.`profession`='Web Developer'
```